# MapView Add mulitple annottion with differenet colors

Tags: ios, iphone, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I have two array of annotations.
From one array I want all pin of green color and from another I want all pin from red color.
I am adding array by this way:

```
 fromSelectedTab=False;
[userMap addAnnotations:greenArray];
 fromSelectedTab=TRUE;
[userMap addAnnotations:redArray];
```

and in viewforannotation I am doing this:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {

if([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    return nil;


 //    static NSString *identifier = @"myAnnotation";
//   // annotation=(MapObjects*)annotation;
//    MKPinAnnotationView * annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView*)[userMap dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
 //    if(!annotationView){
MKPinAnnotationView * annotationView= [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] init ];//WithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:nil];
    //annotationView.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];
annotationView.annotation=annotation;
NSLog(@"flag%d",fromSelectedTab);
    if (fromSelectedTab==TRUE) {
        annotationView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;

    }
    else{
    annotationView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
     //   fromSelectedTab=TRUE;
    }
    annotationView.animatesDrop = NO;

    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

//fromSelectedTab=FALSE;


 //    else {
 //        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
 //    }

//annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
return annotationView;
 }
```

But this way I am getting pin of same color. But I want to in two colors.

Comment: Use different reuse identifiers for green pin colors and red pin color. And use the dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier method also use initWithAnnotation:reuseIdentifier: method and give different reuseidentifier for each color based on the annotation.

Comment: @insane-36 can you tell me how???

Comment: I will show you in example below. By the way you dont have to use two different reuse identifiers.

Comment: @insane-36...where is example?

Comment: Hi were you able to solve the issue ? I have shown you the example below.

Comment: yes...I have tried exactly same but just i didnt know how to cast mapobject to annotation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The custom class which also implements the MKAnnotation protocol is a chance to use our own variable as well. I have created a property called redColor which you could name as you would want.

**MyAnnotation.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MyAnnotation : NSObject<MKAnnotation>

@property (nonatomic, assign, getter = isRedColor) BOOL redColor;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;

- (id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate title:(NSString*)title;


@end
```

**MyAnnotation.m**

```
#import "MyAnnotation.h"

@implementation MyAnnotation

- (id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate title:(NSString*)title{
    if(self = [super init]){
    _coordinate = coordinate;
    _title = title;
  }
  return self;
}

@end
```

**ViewController.h**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import "MyAnnotation.h"

@interface ViewController ()<MKMapViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;


@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  NSMutableArray *allAnnotations = [NSMutableArray array];
  CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake( 50.8500,4.3500);
  MyAnnotation *annotation = [[MyAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinate title:@"Brussels"];
  annotation.redColor = YES;

  [allAnnotations addObject:annotation];


  coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(28.61389, 77.20889);
  annotation = [[MyAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinate title:@"New Delhi"];
  annotation.redColor = NO;

  [allAnnotations addObject:annotation];


  coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(60.1708, 24.9375);
  annotation = [[MyAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinate title:@"Helsinki"];
  annotation.redColor = YES;

  [allAnnotations addObject:annotation];

  coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.5072, 0.1275);
  annotation = [[MyAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinate title:@"London"];
  annotation.redColor = NO;

  [allAnnotations addObject:annotation];

  coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(39.9139, 116.3917);
  annotation = [[MyAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinate title:@"Beijing"];
  annotation.redColor =YES;
  [allAnnotations addObject:annotation];

  [self.mapView showAnnotations:allAnnotations animated:YES];

  [self.mapView addAnnotations:allAnnotations];

}
 #pragma mark - MKMapViewDelegate

- (MKAnnotationView*)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation{
  MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView*)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"PinView"];
  if(!pinView){
    pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"PinView"];
        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
  }
  MyAnnotation *myannotation = (MyAnnotation*)annotation;
  if(myannotation.redColor)
    pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
  else
    pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
  return pinView;
}
@end
```

Comment: here i took string instead of bool variable

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the `addAnnotations` method is probably not synchronous. That means that the `viewForAnnotation` delegate method is not added immediately after the call to `addAnnotations`.

The correct way to fix this problem would be creating a class for the annotations and adding the color property to it. From your code we cannot see the annotation class.

**Follow the procedure below to fix the problem.**

1. Create a class that implements `MKAnnotation` protocol.
2. Add a `BOOL` property named `fromSelectedTab` (or anything else for that matter).
3. Create the array of these classes and set correct color property.
4. Add annotations to the map view.
5. In `viewForAnnotation` method, cast the annotation class and get the color property.
6. Set `MKPinAnnotationView` `pinColor` property based on the property of the annotation class.

The pins should now be in correct color.

Also do not forget to use the `dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:` method when allocating new MKAnnotationView's.

Comment: I have already created that class which have three properties  title subtitle and coordinate. I thought same but I am unable to access annotation.title or annotation.subtitle or annotation.coordinate in viewforannotation method

Comment: Did you cast id<MKAnnotation>annotation to your class?

Comment: Yupp....done....I thought same solution but unable to cast now I search on how to cast and yes done with my functionality